# django_admin database creation, after sql command depreciated

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.9

I was using django 1.3 and python 2.4 for a big scale project. I decided to update it to django 1.9 and python 2.7.

Since django_admin's sql parameter is depreciated in 1.9, the update database creation method changed a lot.

I am using the command:

```
python /usr/local/django/<project>/manage.py migrate --fake-initial --noinput --run-syncdb
```

for table creation. But my tables are not created and manage is printing this error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/project/project-export/django/projectadmin/manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/django/projectadmin/projectadmin/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    import projectadmin.views
  File "/usr/local/django/projectadmin/projectadmin/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from projectadmin.forms import UserCreationForm
  File "/usr/local/django/projectadmin/projectadmin/forms.py", line 252, in <module>
    class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/usr/local/django/projectadmin/projectadmin/forms.py", line 256, in UserCreationForm
    template_choice = form_utils.create_template_choices_field()
  File "/usr/local/django/projectadmin/projectadmin/form_utils.py", line 15, in create_template_choices_field
    choices = [(x.id, x.template_name) for x in all_templates]
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'project.projectadmin_usertemplate' doesn't exist")
```

There is nothing related with table creation in the error. It complains about missing the table but does not create it.

I am suspecting that `INSTALLED_APPS` does not include my tables, but I have appended my application to the list in my `settings.py`.
I got suspicious that I need to add my application separately to the `installed_apps` list.

I have followed recommended procedure by django itself while updating the system.

If my suspicions are true how could I add models to installed apps or any other suggestion would be great?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` first before running `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @hulkinBrain yes I tried it and still the same problem.

Comment: Could you upload the error log?

Comment: If you have created a model, have you registered it in `admin.py`? Not doing that does cause this problem. Add this to your project's admin.py `admin.site.register(youModelName)`. Also could you please show your forms.py code? It would make things very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to django-user mailing list, I have realized my problem was trying to reference a not yet created table before creating it. 
"before it even starts to apply migrations, Django 
needs to import all your packages, so that it can determine what 
migrations it needs to apply. However, in the process of importing 
them, you are already executing database queries against those tables."
Putting those reference fields into a try catch block catching the exception "ProgrammingError" solved my problem.